# Error in mysql shell script, 'Database: command not found'

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am getting the following error while trying to execute this command:

Command:

```
$(mysql -u root -proot -e 'show databases;') > dbnames
```

Error:

```
Database: command not found
```

Comment: Try without the `$()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$( mysql -u ... )` evaluates to the *result* of the `mysql` command. In this example, that string is then treated as a command to execute, and so equivalent to trying to run

```
$ Databases > dbnames
Databases: command not found
```

You simply want to execute the `mysql` command:

```
mysql -u root -proot -e 'show databases;' > dbnames
```